# Does Restlet support parsing URLs into calling methods with parameters?

Tags: java, restlet

Take the following example.

I have a resource

```
public class HelloWorldResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get
    public String represent(String arg) {
        return "hello, world (from the cloud!)" + arg;
    }


}
```

That is mapped by

```
router.attach("/hi/{message}", HelloWorldResource.class);
```

Is it possible to configure the routing such that accessing /hi/somestuffhere will make restlet fill in the arg parameter in the represent method?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`String msg = (String) getRequest().getAttributes().get("message");`

You can place this in an overriden doInit() method in order to let this happen automatically for all your requests to this resource.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample where to attach the route? I'm confused if I should override a method in my `Resource` class or just attach the route when I start my application...